# Migrating Java Shiro Simple Hashes to NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js, hash, sha

In my Company, we used to hash passwords like this in Java, using Shiro's `SimpleHash` class:

```java
new SimpleHash("SHA-512", password, salt, 1024).toBase64()
```

Now, we need to migrate these hashes to NodeJS, i.e. I need to be able to hash passwords in the exact same way to compare them.

So far, I have tried this using the `pbldf2` function from NodeJS's `crypto` module:

```js
// the key length of 64 was determined by looking at the output of SimpleHash, these are 64 bytes long
pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 1024, 64, 'sha512').toString('base64')
```

However, the produced hashes are not the same. I have also tried using `crypto`'s `createHmac` function, but the hashes produced by it did not match either. Notably, I was unable to tell `createHmac` how many iterations should be used.

Comment: First, I know next to nothing about NodeJS. Second, why are you using Key Derivation Function to calculate hash? Shiro implementation of SimpleHash (https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/main/crypto/hash/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/crypto/hash/SimpleHash.java) [refer protected byte[] hash(byte[] bytes, byte[] salt, int hashIterations) method] does (salt+clearText) --> Hash once --> Hash (iteration-1 times). Do same thinh in Node, may be this would be useful (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-hash-digest-method/)

Comment: If you are using strings, make sure they are encoded consistently in both implementations [as warned by the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#using-strings-as-inputs-to-cryptographic-apis)